# Why pytz timezone has extra offset?

Tags: python, pytz

why am I getting extra 4 minute offset? I expected +8:00
https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/philippines/manila

```
import pytz
pytz.timezone('Asia/Manila') # <DstTzInfo 'Asia/Manila' LMT+8:04:00 STD>
pytz.VERSION #  '2017.2'
```